How Long Can I Drive A Car Without Coolant?
Ive been driving without coolant for some time. Just noticed there wasn't any in there. Car runs fine and never noticed it was empty. I filled it back up. No leaks. Should I be extra cautious get my engine checked out for possible damage?

My old 1968 VW Bug ran just fine without coolant...

Did you fill the coolant reservoir on your VW Bug?

It's more likely that you've discovered that the coolant reservoir, sometimes called the coolant overflow tank was empty, not the engine in its entirety. An engine devoid of coolant will self-destruct in short order, seizing up solid.
If you received no dashboard indications of a problem, it's unlikely that you have had any damage. If you want additional reassurance and have not had cooling system maintenance, consider to have your cooling system flushed and the coolant replaced.
